# SSIS Package OLEDB Source Timeout property is not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am trying to use timeout property on OLEDB Source in SSIS package, i set timeout property to 60 seconds and i know my source query takes 1 hour to finish. After setting timeout property i executed the package but package/OLEDB source didn't stopped executing.

Comment: if you really want to force a timeout, then you might use script component as a data source. It would definitely expires after 60 seconds.

Comment: but timeout property on OLEDB suppose to do the same thing rite? i am sure so many people faced this problem and sure they might figured a best solution.

Answer (score 0):

timeout is a connection property... Means , if the client cannot connect to the server via 60 sec then the error will be thrown